# How can I solve "Uncaught Error: Container is not defined"?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create dynamic variables, I keep getting

> **Uncaught Error: Container is not defined**

I double-checked everything - line by line - still couldn't find my own mistake.
I hope someone can point out what I missed.

---

## JS

```
  var data = {};
  var chart = {};

  for (var object in objects) {

    var total = objects[object].danger + objects[object].warning + objects[object].success ;

    data[object] = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([

      ['Piechart' , 'Number of Skills'],
      ['danger'   , ( objects[object].danger/total )  * 100  ],
      ['warning'  , ( objects[object].warning/total ) * 100  ],
      ['success'  , ( objects[object].success/total ) * 100  ],

      ]);

    console.log( ".piechart-div-"+ object.toLowerCase() );

    var $el = $('#sa-piechart-' + object);

    $el.length ? $('#sa-piechart-' + object.toLowerCase() ) :
    $('<div id="#sa-piechart-' + object.toLowerCase() +'"></div>')
    .appendTo(".piechart-div-" + object.toLowerCase());

    // Dynamic Variables
    chart[object] = new google.visualization.PieChart($el[0]);

    // Dynamic On Click Binding
    $('.sa-report-btn-'+ object.toLowerCase() ).click(function() {
      updateInfo(object);
      chart[object].draw( data[object] , options );
    });

  }
```

---

## HTML

```
<div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2 piechart-div-a">
   <div id="sa-piechart-a"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: try $('.sa-report-btn-'+ object.toLowerCase() ).on('click', function() { instead of using a click if the buttons are dynamically created

Comment: Hello, i hope to help, i think your problem is in "for (var object in objects)", because not created 'objects'

Comment: @DhirajBodicherla : Thank-you so much for your enthusiasm to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, there is no `piechart-div-*` to append `sa-piechart` div to.

- Create piechart container
- Create piechart div
- Append piechart div to container
- Create button and attach event handler [(using bind since its inside a loop)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Something like this should do it

```
// create a piechart object
var $el = $('#sa-piechart-' + object);

// create a piechart container
var pieChartContainer = $('<div></div>').addClass('piechart-div-' + object.toLowerCase());

// append piechart container to body (or any other container)
$('body').append(pieChartContainer);
$el = $el.length ? $('#sa-piechart-' + object.toLowerCase()) : $('<div id="#sa-piechart-' + object.toLowerCase() + '"></div>')
  .appendTo(pieChartContainer);

// create a button and append to chart container
var button = $('<input type="button" value="report" />');
pieChartContainer.append(button);

// attach click handler to the created button
$(button).click(function (chart, data, obj) {
  updateInfo(obj);
  chart.draw(data);
}.bind(null, chart[object], data[object], object)); // <--- passing variables here
```

Here is a demo **http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/6M2sH/445/**

Comment: I couldn't get my chart to draw. :(

Comment: I got error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'draw' of undefined`

Comment: 1. the way button is created is different
2. on line 21 create id without `#` for `sa-piechart-`

Comment: Sadly, I still get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'draw' of undefined`